# Parsing Xml large file shutdown the server nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, xml-parsing, sails.js

I have written code in node js, I get XML data in a stream from the server, then parse it. locally it works fine, but when I deploy on the server, it shut down the server node.

it takes 100% CPU usage. Is there any way to minimum use CPU usage?
Any expert opinion

```
  const axios = require('axios'),
  node_xml_stream = require('node-xml-stream'),
  httpAdapter = require('axios/lib/adapters/http');
  let response;
    try {
      sails.log.info('Before http stream request');
      response = await axios.get(process.env.SRO_FEED_URL, {
        responseType: 'stream',
        adapter: httpAdapter
      });
    } catch (error) {
      sails.log.error('http request error ', error);
    }

    const stream = response.data;
    sails.log.info('After the feed response');
    parser = new node_xml_stream(),
    stream.pipe(parser);

parser.on('opentag', 
function(name, attrs) {       
if (name === 'job') {         
// let attr = attrs;       
}       
t_name = name;     })

parser.on('text', function(text) {
  if (t_name === 'id') {
    id = text;
  }
  if (t_name === 'company') {
    company = text;
  }
});
```

code locally working fine, but when I deploy its crash the server.
I'm having a tough time finding a node package that can parse large XML files that are 1G+ in size.

Comment: Parser method in comments

Comment: `parser.on('opentag', function(name, attrs) {
      if (name === 'job') {
        // let attr = attrs;
      }
      t_name = name;
    });`

Comment: i am using this parser library for parsing data

[https://github.com/snappyjs/node-xml-stream]

Comment: do you have the sample XML file (1gb) so that others can test?

Comment: sorry. I am using company private data